# Infectious diabetes

Tags: diseases, viruses

I want to know if the disease I invented is realistic or a total fiction.

I imagined a hypothetical viral disease that causes a contagious form of diabetes. It is only transmitted by blood. The virus that causes it is a RNA virus from the *Flasuviricetes* class. Consequently, it is related to hepatitis C virus, West Nile virus, and Yellow fever virus.

But, is there a real life infectious disease that can be considered a transmissible diabetes?

Comment: First google result for "insulin virus": https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/02/180219155012.htm

Comment: Lacking world-building context and being purely medical, I suggest posting this on [medicalsciences.se]. Do read their posting requirements first though.

Comment: Any such infectious agent would have to kill or cause the pancreas to stop functioning, either directly affecting the pancreas or altering the immune system to attack the pancreas, as what happens with childhood (type 1) diabetes. The disease would need to destroy the pancreatic islet cells that produce insulin - thus mimicking type 1 diabetes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The simple answer is it's realistic**

> Type 1 diabetes occurs when your immune system, the body’s system for fighting infection, attacks and destroys the insulin-producing beta cells of the pancreas. Scientists think type 1 diabetes is caused by genes and environmental factors, ***such as viruses,*** that might trigger the disease. Studies such as TrialNet External link are working to pinpoint causes of type 1 diabetes and possible ways to prevent or slow the disease. (Emphasis added, [Source](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/diabetes/overview/symptoms-causes))

And, asking what virus could do this...

> Enteroviruses are a group of viruses that usually cause mild illnesses, like the common cold. Certain strains of enterovirus—such as the poliovirus, enterovirus-D68, and coxackievirus (also known as hand, foot, and mouth disease)—can cause more serious symptoms.
>
> Previous research has also suggested that children exposed to enteroviruses are more likely to develop type 1 diabetes. ([Source](https://www.health.com/condition/type-1-diabetes/diabetes-enterovirus))

Which means real life has already beaten you to the idea. Sorry. However, the science is far from perfect.

> The most popular hypothesis circulating within and beyond the scientific community is that viral infections enhance or elicit autoimmune disorders such as type 1 diabetes. Indeed, viruses can injure β-cells and have been isolated in pancreatic tissues from diabetic patients. However, accumulating evidence suggests that the opposite scenario, which is prevention or amelioration of type 1 diabetes, might be at least as common an outcome of viral infection. Here, we discuss epidemiological and experimental evidence for the main mechanisms accounting for the role of viruses in type 1 diabetes to better understand the complex relationship between viral infections and autoimmune diabetes. ([Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2570378/))

So, yes, it appears realistic to have an "infectious diabetes" in the form of a virus that causes the autoimmune disorder, which already has some scientific merit.

However, I leave it to you to evaluate Enteroviruses. IMHO it would be better to use a mutated form of such a virus rather than inventing a new transport mechanism (i.e., your second paragraph). It make the disease more believable.

Comment: While I'm delighted to receive the coveted green check mark... we recommend that you not hand it out for at least 24 hours. The Stack has users around the world and human nature is to ignore questions that have accepted answers. You might discover a better answer than my own.

Comment: Good to see you back --- you've been sorely missed!!!   Good "Real World Frame Challenges the Fictional" sort of scenario, this.